# Trying to use * pointer operator to call class member function

Tags: c++

I'm a begginer in C++ and trying to create a new instance of a class

```
foo* a= new foo(1);
*(a).kCreateThread();
```

and I get the following error

> error C2228: left of '.kCreateThread' must have class/struct/union

What is wrong?

Comment: `(*a).kCreateThread();`. Your syntax tries to call a.kCreateThread() and dereference the return value of it, while mine first dereferences the pointer a and then tries to call kCreateThread with it. This is because * has lower precedence then .

Comment: [This operator precedence table might help.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you wrote is equivalent to

```
*((a).kCreateThread());
```

You should use

```
a->kCreateThread();
```

or

```
(*a).kCreateThread();
```

These last two are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:
a->kCreateThread();